# Issue with reference class library to project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core RC2 application which was migrated from RC1.

I had reference to class library (.net framework 4.5) and I want to add it to my RC2 application.
So I changed project.json like this

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"frameworks": {
    "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
                "ExtConfig.PortalRepository": "1.0.0-*"
            }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "dnxcore50",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ],
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
                "type": "platform"
            },
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Routing": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
            "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
        }
    }

},
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"
},
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
}
}
```

And it is built ok, but for RC2 application it is not visible.
I have advice from ReSharper, but it doesn't work.
[image]

I tried to change net45 to diffirent dnx and netstandard statements, but it didn't help too. And I created nuget package from class library and tried to add it like nuget package and it didn't work.

Anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: You have no reference for that package in your .NET Core dependencies. Add a reference for it, choose not to use it in your project, or `#IFDEF` your way around it.

Comment: I can't add it to .NET Core dependencies because it'll write that "The dependency couldn't be resolved"
http://i.imgur.com/fz5Jj6T.png

Comment: So do one of the other things I recommended. Not all packages are ready for .NET Core yet.

Comment: This library is used a lot in project, I can't choose not to use it =(
Thak you for your answer!

Comment: Contact the library developer and ask them to get it updated for .NET Core. Or if it's open source, try to update it yourself.

Comment: Also, it appears that library was removed from NuGet. That's [not good](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtConfig.PortalRepository/). Generally that's only done in extenuating circumstances. I wouldn't build my app around a dependency that isn't solid.

Comment: I have the same issue with .net core class library.
http://i.imgur.com/PVyrhJe.png

Comment: All that's saying is that you have to add a reference to it in order to be able to use the code from it. That reference can take the form of a NuGet package, a compiled DLL, or another project that you have the source code for.

Comment: I created a new .net core class library and added a reference from asp.net  core to it. And it is not visible.

Comment: That's a new question now.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use Resharper. .NET Core is heavily in flux right now, I doubt their tooling is up to date. Just disable Resharper while using .NET Core.

Comment: ReSharper gives me an advice, but first, I was trying to resolve it by myself.
I'll create a new question about adding references to .net core from asp.net core.

Comment: I don't think you understand what .NET Core and how Resharper is related to it. .NET Core is under heavy development. It's constantly changing. Visual Studio can barely keep up with the changes. Resharper tooling is not going to be aware of how everything works in .NET Core and is going to give you misleading information until things stabilize.

Comment: Do you plan on deploying this to a windows box, if so you can use the `net45` TFM for example. https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it ReSharper which trying to resolve references? Maybe it's not compatible with the new RC2 / SDK Preview yet, so...

Disable ReSharper's code analysis.

```
Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings -> General -> Enable code analysis
```

Untick it

```
Save
```

If still can't resolve references, try reinstall RC2
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2/

Or run visual studio in safe mode, maybe there is an extensions blow up things.

```
denenv.exe /safemode
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx